# iOS Push notifications via GCM not sending overnight

Tags: ios, google-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

My app doesn't receive GCM push notifications if it has been in the background for a long time (ex: overnight). If the app is restarted (double tap home, swipe away, restart app) then the queued messages get delivered.

Our app receives a data payload, and then constructs an iOS local notification with the contents of the payload.

It is working for the following scenarios: app in foreground, app in background (hit home button), app is killed (double tap home, swipe away app).

Payload

```
{
    "data": {
        "title":"Test Title",
        "message": "Message body",
    },
    "content_available":true,
    "priority": "high"
}
```

Why would it work if the app is killed but not when it's been in the background for a long time. Is it a difference between the app being terminated vs suspended?

Okay I did some testing and here's what appears to be happening.

## Test cases

**note**: We were doing some things that GCM doesn't do in their in their example. We connect to GCM on app startup (not `applicationDidBecomeActive` and we do not disconnect from GCM during `applicationDidEnterBackground`)

### App in background, device is not awake

1. trigger GCM message, nothing happens
2. when device is woken (press hold button), `didReceiveRemoteNotification` gets called, which creates a local notification

### App is killed (double tap home, swipe app away), device is not awake

1. trigger GCM message, nothing happens
2. when device is woken, the apps `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` executes
3. because we were connecting to GCM here, it also calls `didReceiveRemoteNotification`

#### So why doesn't it work when the app is in the background for a long time?

My theory is GCM sets up some background task when it's set up for the first time. This background task listens for GCM messages and executes `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` if the app is terminated. However when an app is suspended, it can be terminated without warning. If this happens I theorize that this background task for whatever fails to execute, and since the app is terminated there's no connection to GCM.

## Solution

Probably use the [(ctrl-f) Hybrid messages with both notification and data payload](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages)

Comment: Which versions of iOS are you targeting and which `didReceiveRemoteNotification` function did you implement? The one with or without the completion handler? Or both since I have found even with iOS 8 and up GCM says only use the one with the completion handler it drops a warning for me that I have not implemented all the needed delegate functions until I add the other one even though it never calls it.

Comment: both functions are implemented

Comment: Check the "lifetime of a message" section of the referenced documentation. Since its in the background (idle), it will be delivered right away unless `delay_while_idle` is set. Otherwise it will be stored in the server until connection is restored.

Comment: So we were using AWS SNS and GCM. It looks like SNS has not yet fully implemented the GCM spec, particularly lacking "priority" https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=700294